# "ListAccounts" access denied in AWS IAM policy

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam

I have multiple AWS accounts with root account used for consolidated billing. A third party is doing a call to my AWS accounts which requires access to listaccount api, I am getting access denied in each account even after adding this access to the policy

Answer (score 3):

from the [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/organizations/latest/APIReference/API_ListAccounts.html)

> This operation can be called only from the organization's management account or by a member account that is a delegated administrator for an AWS service.

Comment: You meant root account that is managing the consolidated billing? How can we a make member accoun a delegated administrator

Comment: yes, you can checkout  [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/organizations/latest/userguide/orgs_integrate_services_list.html) for various services for delegated administrator